# MongoDB query to search for user based on multiple parameters

Tags: database, mongodb, express, nosql, schema

I have no idea how to deal with MongoDB, and I tried and failed.

The problem as following:

I have data gathered from URL. This data is: text, location, skills, type, hasJob, hasItem.

This data used to search for a user in database has matched values with these parameters.

for example, this is an URL: http://localhost:3000/profile/search/?type=exact&skills=Test,Programming&text=salam&location=uk

```
text=salam
type=exact
skills=[Test, Programming]
location=uk
```

The required query should do the following: if there is matched name and location and skills, the query should return the user that has these matched data. But, if there is a matched name and location and text without any skills matches, the query also should return the user.

So, the skills may be matched or not, in all cases, the query should return user if there is a matched name and location as text.

This is the search end-point that should does the work:

```
router.get('/search', (req, res) => {
  if (!req.query || !req.query.type || (!req.query.text && !req.query.skills && !req.query.location)) {
    return res.status(400).json({status: 'bad', error: 'Missing required fields.'});
  }


  if (req.query.type !== 'fuzzy' && req.query.type !== 'exact') {
    return res.status(400).json({status: 'bad', error: 'Invalid type.'});
  }

  const user = req.user;
  const exact = req.query.type === 'exact';

  let result = [];
  let searchBuilder = {};
  let searchQuery = [];

  let locationResult =[];
  let textResult = [];
  let skillsResuts = [];
  let locationData=[];
  let textData=[];
  let skillsData= [];
  let skills =[];
  let item = {};


//1- Location
  if (req.query.location) {
      locationData = [
        {'profile.address.city': { $regex: req.query.location }},
        {'profile.address.country': { $regex: req.query.location }},
        {'profile.address.state': { $regex: req.query.location }},
        {'profile.address.zip': { $regex: req.query.location }}
    ]
    searchBuilder['$or'] = locationData;
    searchQuery.push({
        '$or': locationData
    })
  }


//2- Text
  if (req.query.text) {
      textData = [
          { 'phone': req.query.text },
          {'profile.fullName': { $regex: req.query.text }},
          {'profile.email': { $regex: req.query.text }},
          // {'profile.username': { $regex: req.query.text }}
      ]
      searchBuilder['$or'] = textData;
      searchQuery.push({
          '$or': textData
      })
  }

//3- Skills
  if (req.query.skills) {

      let allSkills = req.query.skills.split(',')
     skillsData = {
         'profile.skills.custom.name': { '$in': allSkills }
     }

     skills = allSkills.map(function(v, i){return new RegExp(v, 'i')});

      searchBuilder['profile.skills.custom.name'] = { '$in': skills }
      item = {'profile.skills.custom.name': { '$in': skills }};
      searchQuery.push({
          '$or': [ skillsData ]
      })
  }


//4. hasJobs
  if (req.query.hasJobs) {
      searchBuilder['jobs.0'] = { $exists: true };
      searchQuery.push({
          'jobs.0': { '$exists': true }
      })
  }

//5.hasItems
  if (req.query.hasItems) {
      searchBuilder['items.0'] = { $exists: true };
      searchQuery.push({
          'items.0': { '$exists': true }
      })
  }


// Add the query here 
  db.User.find({}})
    .populate('connections.user')
    .populate('jobs')
    .populate('items')
    .populate('profile.skills.custom')
    .select('-contacts')
    .sort('connections.user.profile.fullName')
    .then(users => {
      async.each(users, (user, next) => {
        if (user.id === req.user.id) {
          return next();
        }
        const check = result.find(usr => {
          return usr.id === user.id;
        });
        if (!check) {
          result.push(user);
          next();
        }
        else {
          return next();
        }
      })
    })
    .then(() => {
      res.json(result);
    })
    .catch(err => {
      return res.status(400).json({status: 'bad', error: err});
    });


});
```

and this is the schema

```
const UserSchema = new Schema({
  phone: String,
  shortPhone: String,
  password: String,
  profile: {
    email: String,
    fullName: String,
    username: String,
    address: {
      city: {type: String, default: 'Unknown'},
      state: String,
      country: String,
      zip: String,
    },
    photos: String,
    summary: String,
    resume: String,
    resumeFile: String,
    experiences: [{
      title: String,
      company: String,
      location: String,
      startDate: Date,
      endDate: Date,
      description: String
    }],
    educations: [{
      school: String,
      degree: String,
      field: String,
      startDate: Date,
      endDate: Date,
      description: String
    }],
    skills: {
      standard: [{type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Skill'}],
      custom: [{name: String}]
    },
    points: {type: Number, default: 0},
    totalPoints: {type: Number, default: 0},
    hidden: {type: Boolean, default: false},
    public: {type: Boolean, default: true},
    countryCode: String,
  },
  location: {type: [Number], index: '2d'},
  items: [{type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Item'}],
  blogs: [{type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Blog'}],
  news: [{type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'News'}],
  conversations: [{type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Conversation'}],
  viewBy: [{type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User'}],
  level: {type: Number, default: 1},
  verified: {type: Boolean, default: false},
  notificationTokens: [{type: String}],
  connections: [{
    user: {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User'},
    relationship: {type: String, enum: ['requested', 'received', 'connected']},
    isForced: {type: Boolean, default: false}
  }],
  declinedRequests: [String],
  jobs: [{type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Job'}],
  favoritedJobs: [{type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Job'}],
  sharedJobs: [{type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Job'}],
  viewedJobs: [{type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Job'}],
  favoritedItems: [{type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Item'}],
  sharedItems: [{type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Item'}],
  viewedItems: [{type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Item'}],
  actions: [{type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Action'}],
  incentives: [{type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Incentive'}],
  contacts: [String],
  synced: {type: Boolean, default: false}
});

//UserSchema.plugin(autoPopulateAllFields);

exports.User = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);
```

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: @sameeralakshitha: when editing a question, the edit reason is to summarise the change, not to repeat the question itself.